# Unable to return base case value in Recursion problem

Tags: java, if-statement, recursion, return-value, binary-search

Edit: Thanks for the answers I got it!

I have just started learning Data Structures and I can't seem to figure out why the base case isn't working. In this method, we are supposed to split the array we get and search the key if it's bigger/smaller than where you split. Find the method below (I took out most of the sys.out.println because stack overflow said i had too much code ):-

```
public static int nSearch (int n, int a[], int fromIndex, int toIndex, int key){

      //base case
      if ((toIndex - fromIndex) <= n) 
      { // if there is only one element per split or less

          for (int i = fromIndex; i < toIndex; i++) {
        
              if (a[i] == key) {
                  System.out.println("If a[i] == key runs.");
                  return i;
              }
          }
          return -1;
      }
      
      int splitIndex = a.length/n; //2

      if (key >= a[splitIndex]) { // if key is bigger/equal to a[splitIndex], meaning the range is 2-3
          
          nSearch (n, a, splitIndex, a.length, key);
          
      }
      else {

          //else the range is 0-1
          nSearch (n, a, 0, splitIndex, key);
      }

      return 0;
  }
```

This is what the Console returns when I send a test case:

```
My Search Tester 2 is Running Now.
Array Length: - 4
Starting nSearch: - n : 2 fromIndex : 0 toIndex : 4
false
Case 1: n = 2 SplitIndex Value = 2 aLength = 4 Key value = 4
Starting nSearch: - n : 2 fromIndex : 2 toIndex : 4
true
Base Case Running
For loop Running
fromIndex : 2 toIndex : 4
i : 2 a[i] : 3 Key : 4
For loop Running
fromIndex : 2 toIndex : 4
i : 3 a[i] : 4 Key : 4
If a[i] == key runs.
Target 4 is at Index := 0
```

As you can see, the output shows that control enters the `if (a[i] == key)` block, but I don't understand why `return i` doesn't work.  Please tell me what I did wrong.

I can't post the tester code, lest SO reject my post as being mostly code, but here is the test case I'm using:

```
int arr = {1,2,3,4}
nSearch(2, arr, 0, arr.length, 4);
```

The `nSearch` method is supposed to be a variation of binary search, if that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I don't understand why `return i` doesn't work

There is no reason to think that the `return` statement does not work as advertised, but in most cases, the program ignores the resulting return value.

But note the `return 0` at the end of your method.  Under what circumstances do you think it would be appropriate for that to be executed?  Answer: none.  I suspect that you added it to clear the compiler's objection about control reaching the end of a non-void method, but if so, then you should have looked deeper: why does control ever reach that point in the first place?

Consider the immediately preceding bit:

> ```
>       if (key >= a[splitIndex]) { // if key is bigger/equal to a[splitIndex], meaning the range is 2-3
>           
>           nSearch (n, a, splitIndex, a.length, key);
>           
>       }
>       else {
>
>           //else the range is 0-1
>           nSearch (n, a, 0, splitIndex, key);
>       }
> ```

In each branch you invoke `nSearch()` recursively, but what happens when the recursive call returns?  Nothing special.  Control just continues from there, directly to that errant `return 0`, which produces the 0 return value that the tester reports.  Whatever value was returned by the recursive call is ignored.

This variation on the last few lines of your method should work better for you:

```
  if (key >= a[splitIndex]) {          
      return nSearch(n, a, splitIndex, a.length, key);
  } else {
      return nSearch(n, a, 0, splitIndex, key);
  }

  // return 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should terminate the recursion after you got result from an inner recursion. Also, in this `nSearch (n, a, splitIndex, a.length, key);`, you are checking till `a.length`, irrespective of what actual toIndex was in this method call(same for fromIndex). So following changes should give you correct answer.

```
if (key >= a[splitIndex]) {          
    return nSearch(n, a, splitIndex, toIndex, key);
} 
else {
    return nSearch(n, a, fromIndex, splitIndex, key);
}
```